# stream server-side chat message POST

Tags: server-side, getstream-io

i would like to post new messages to a chat channel directly from my back-end. I can see how to do it on feeds, but can't find anything similar for chat.
What's the most straight forward way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can send messages from your backend in Stream Chat using something such as this

```
const searchAndSendMessage = async (channelID, userID, message) => {
  const filterID = { id: channelID };
  const channel = await client.queryChannels(filterID, {});
  channel[0].sendMessage({user: { id: userID }, text: message})
  return channel[0];
};
```

Please note that when sending a message from the backend using server-side auth, then you'll need to include either `message.user` or `message.user_id` else you will throw an error.